# How To Remove Certain category Posts From the Blog Page

Tags: posts, categories

I'd like to know, Is there any ways to remove certain category posts from the blog page.

Actually, I own a technology blog and I'd like to implement free software directory or marketplace in my blog within download category. But The download category post will not display in the blog page and only accessible from download category. I have heard about some plugin but I trust codes instead of the plugin.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to make use of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) which change the query vars just before the main query is executed.

Here is an example from the codex to exclude categories from the home page/blog page. For a full list of available parameters and values that you can use with `pre_get_posts`, visit the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) codex page

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```